# How fast is the Warpfall Transmitter?

Tags: titanfall

The Warpfall Transmitter, a Tier 2 loadout option,

> accelerates your Titanfall substantially, using short-range jump technology.

Great.  What does that actually mean in terms of time-to-fall?  Is it an insta-gib button to smash people with?

Comment: With warpfall there's a great trick you can pull - rodeo a titan, and as soon as they drop to get out jump off and call titanfall over the crouched titan. Most times your titan will crush both the pilot and their titan. This works without warpfall, but far less often as they've had time to take a step or two away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer:

- Standard Titanfall: **5 seconds**
- With Warpfall Transmitter: approximately **2.5 seconds**

From what I remember from the beta, it's not an instant gib option or anything. It just speeds up the "Titanfall" animations.

Never really used it myself, only saw it in a few videos. It will just shorten the delay quite significantly.

The following video explains and visualizes the difference quite nicely (the interesting part starts at 1m44s; watch it as a whole if you want more details):